# HTML formated text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have stored text in **HTML** format to database and want to dynamically show in textarea or something like this.

This is textarea

```
<textarea class="FormElement" name="txtObject" id="term" style="width: 320px; height: 250px;"></textarea>
```

and set value with javascript

```
$('[name=txtObject]').val(row.Text);
```

but get `<strong>Text message</strong>`
I want to get **Text message**.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Textareas are, as their name suggests, areas of text. *Text.* Not HTML. Consider using a `<div>` with `contentEditable`.

Comment: use div instead......

Comment: **Nope** You can't render html within textarea

Comment: @rejesh can you give me example how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A textarea is just supposed to be used to enter unformatted text. If you just want to display the text, add it to a div instead, should work with `$('#mydiv').html(row.Text)`. If you want a more rich text editor I'd suggest to google around for one that is suitable for you.

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) seems to be a resonable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with a `textarea`. The result you want to achieve is possible with a content editable div , like so :

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: If anyone is concerned with backwards compatability, the `contenteditable` runs on all modern browsers back to (and including) IE8 - http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable